# Is my usage of explicit casting operator reasonable or a bad hack?

Tags: c#, object-oriented, .net, type-casting

I have a big object:

```
class BigObject{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string FieldA {get;set;}
    // ...
    public string FieldZ {get;set;}
}
```

and a specialized, DTO-like object:

```
class SmallObject{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public EnumType Type {get;set;}
    public string FieldC {get;set;}
    public string FieldN {get;set;}
}
```

I personally find a concept of explicitly casting BigObject into SmallObject - knowing that it is a one-way, data-losing operation - very intuitive and readable:

```
var small = (SmallObject) bigOne;
passSmallObjectToSomeone(small);
```

It is implemented using explicit operator:

```
public static explicit operator SmallObject(BigObject big){
    return new SmallObject{
        Id = big.Id,
        FieldC = big.FieldC,
        FieldN = big.FieldN,
        EnumType = MyEnum.BigObjectSpecific
    };
}
```

Now, I could create a `SmallObjectFactory` class with `FromBigObject(BigObject big)` method, that would do the same thing, add it to dependency injection and call it when needed... but to me it seems even more overcomplicated and unnecessary.

PS I'm not sure if this is relevant, but there will be `OtherBigObject` that will also be able to be converted into `SmallObject`, setting different `EnumType`.

Comment: Why not a constructor?

Comment: Or a static factory method?

Comment: Why would you need a factory class, or dependency injection? You've made a false dichotomy there.

Comment: @immibis - because I somehow did not think about what @Telastyn proposed: `.ToSmallObject()` method (or `GetSmallObject()`). A momentary lapse of reason - I knew something is wrong with my thinking, so I've asked you guys :)

Comment: this kind of conversion is common in c++ not in C#...

Comment: This sounds like a perfect use case for an ISmallObject interface which is only implemented by BigObject as a means to provide access to a limited set of its extensive data/behavior. Especially when combined with @Telastyn's idea of a `ToSmallObject` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the other answers have it right in my humble opinion. In this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678217/best-practices-for-mapping-dto-to-domain-object) the highest-voted answer argues that mapping code should be kept out of the domain. To answer your question, no - your usage of the cast operator is not great. I would advise to make a mapping service which sits between your DTO and you domain object, or you could use automapper for that.

Comment: This is a terrific idea. I already have Automapper in place, so it will be a breeze.

Only issue I have with it: shouldn't there be some trace that BigObject and SmallObject are somehow related?

Comment: No I don't see any advantage by coupling BigObject and SmallObject further together other than the mapping service.

Comment: I'll change accepted solution to yours, as I have followed your advice. It is working, it seems clean and readable from all angles. I think that other solutions might be better if the solution is very small (no mapping service whatsoever), but in my case it's perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Really? An automapper is your solution for design problems?

Comment: The BigObject is mappable to SmallObject, they are not really related to each other in classical OOP sense, and code reflects this (both objects exist in domain, mapping ability is set in mapping config along with many others). It does remove dubious code (my unfortunate operator override), it leaves models clean (no methods in them), so yeah, it seems to be a solution.

Comment: @Gerino - Automappers aren't a ***solution*** they're duck tape and bailing wire holding together a bomb.

Comment: @telastyn if you read the so i linked to it seems clear that neither domain objects nor dto should know about each other. it has to be a service between. how this service is implemented is an implementation detail.

Comment: @EsbenSkovPedersen This solution is like using a bulldozer to dig a hole to install your mailbox.  Luckily the OP wanted to dig up the yard anyway, so a bulldozer works in this case.  However, I wouldn't recommend this solution *in general*.

Comment: @Neil I know you are exacurating, but clearly the Domain objects and DTOs belong in different layers so in a standard layered architecture there is nothing extreme about keeping them seperated with services.

Comment: @Neil yeah, and I've commented on that earlier - "other solutions might be better (...) in my case it's perfect" :)

Comment: @EsbenSkovPedersen I just feel like it should be well noted.  Though if this resolves Gerino's issue, then it would be wrong to downvote it.

Comment: The question and the answer are only coincidentally related...

Answer (score 81):

It is... Not great. I've worked with code that did this clever trick and it led to confusion. After all, you would expect to be able to just assign the `BigObject` into a `SmallObject` variable if the objects are related enough to cast them. It doesn't work though - you get compiler errors if you try since as far as the type system is concerned, they're unrelated. It is also mildly distasteful for the casting operator to make new objects.

I would recommend a `.ToSmallObject()` method instead. It is clearer about what is actually going on and about as verbose.

Comment: Doh... ToSmallObject() seems like the most obvious choice. Sometimes most obvious is the most elusive ;)

Comment: `mildly distasteful` is an understatement. It's unfortunate that the language allows this sort of thing to look like a typecast. Nobody would guess it was an actual object transformation unless they wrote it themselves. In a one-person team, fine. If you collaborate with anyone, in the best case it's a waste of time because you have to stop and figure out if it's really a cast, or if it's one of those crazy transforms.

Comment: @KentAnderson - perhaps. Though I've worked with enough crap that something slightly weird that causes readability issues (but works and doesn't cause pervasive structural problems) is not high on my distasteful list.

Comment: @Telastyn Agreed that it's not the most egregious code smell. But the hidden creation of a new object from on operation that most programmers understand to be an instruction to the compiler to treat _that same object_ as a different type, is unkind to anyone who has to work with your code after you. :)

Comment: +1 for `.ToSmallObject()`. Hardly ever should you override operators.

Comment: I still find it lightly confusing that `.ToSmallObject()` would be a data-losing operation. Why not `.GetSmallObject()`, populated with the data from `BigObject`?

Comment: @dorus - at least in .NET, `Get` implies returning an existing thing. Unless you've overridden the operations on the small object, two `Get` calls would return unequal objects, causing confusion/bugs/wtfs.

Comment: @Telastyn true, might actually be a good idea to implement this properly and encapsulate a `SmallObject` as well.

Comment: You could avoid the copying by using an ISmallObject interface implemented by BigObject and simply return a reference to `this` in the ToSmallObject implementation.

Comment: The same idea in the other direction yields having a `FromBigObject` factory method on SmallObject. Which direction makes more sense depends on the context.

Comment: I'd probably do this as an extension method if possible.

Answer (score 11):

While I can see why you would need to have a `SmallObject`, I would approach the problem differently.  My approach to this type of issue is to use a [Facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern).  Its sole purpose is to encapsulate `BigObject` and only make available specific members.  In this way, it is a new interface on the same instance, and not a copy.  Of course you may *also* want to perform a copy, but I would recommend that you do so through a method created for that purpose in combination with the Facade (for instance `return new SmallObject(instance.Clone())`).

Facade has a number of other advantages, namely ensuring that certain sections of your program can only make use of the members made available through your facade, effectively guaranteeing that it cannot make use of what it shouldn't know about.  In addition to this, it also has the enormous advantage that you have more flexibility in changing `BigObject` in future maintenance without having to worry too much about how it is used throughout your program.  So long as you can emulate the old behavior in some form or another, you can make `SmallObject` work the same as it did before without having to change your program everywhere `BigObject` would have been used.

Note, this means `BigObject` does not depend on `SmallObject` but rather the other way around (as it should be in my humble opinion).

Comment: The only advantage you mentioned that a facade has over copying fields to a new class is avoiding the copying (which is probably not a problem unless the objects have an absurd amount of fields). On the other hand it has the disadvantage that you must modify the original class every time you need to convert to a new class, unlike a static conversion method.

Comment: @Doval I suppose that's the point.  You wouldn't convert it to a new class.  You'd create another facade if that's what you require.  Changes made to BigObject need only be applied to the Facade class and not everywhere where it is used.

Comment: One interesting distinction between this approach and [Telastyn's answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/281981/15162) is whether responsibility for generating `SmallObject` lies with `SmallObject` or `BigObject`.  By default, this approach forces   `SmallObject` to avoid dependencies on private/protected members of `BigObject`.  We can go a step further and avoid dependencies on private/protected members of `SmallObject` by using a `ToSmallObject` extension method.

Comment: @Brian You risk cluttering `BigObject` that way.  If you wanted to do something similar, you'd vouche for creating a `ToAnotherObject` extension method within `BigObject`?  These should not be the concerns of `BigObject` since, presumably, it is already large enough as it is.  It also allows you to separate `BigObject` from the creation of its dependencies, meaning you could use factories and the like.  The other approach strongly couples `BigObject` and `SmallObject`.  That may be fine in this particular case, but it isn't best practice in my humble opinion.

Comment: @Neil: No, by default using an extension method avoids coupling entirely, since an extension method would lack the ability to access private members either of the two objects.

Comment: @Brian Coupling says nothing about accessing private members, it is about the level of dependency one has with the other.  It means SmallObject is useless without the data from BigObject and BigObject creates SmallObjects, making them strongly coupled.  It is enough that SmallObject depends on BigObject, though BigObject has no business knowing about SmallObject.

Comment: @Neil Actually, Brian explained it wrong, but he *is* right - extension methods do get rid of the coupling. It's no longer `BigObject` being coupled to `SmallObject`, it's just a static method somewhere that takes an argument of `BigObject` and returns `SmallObject`. Extension methods really are just syntactic sugar to call static methods in a nicer way. The extension method is not *part* of `BigObject`, it's a completely separate static method. It's actually a pretty good use of extension methods, and very handy for DTO conversions in particular.

Comment: @Luaan Ah, I'm not familiar with extension methods.  Then in theory one could define such an extension method in SmallObject?

Comment: @Neil It actually has to be defined in a static class, so it's quite explicitly separate from anything it could be used on. You *can't* define it in either `SmallObject` nor `BigObject`. For example, you might have a static class like `DtoConversionExtensions`, which would have the conversion extension methods for all the DTOs. Or any other granularity you want - the key point is you don't really have any dependencies. It will *look* like part of `BigObject` (you can call it like `BigObject.ToSmallObject`), but that's just the syntactic sugar - it's actually `DtoConversions.ToSmallObject(...)`

Answer (score 6):

There is a very strong convention that casts on mutable reference types are identity-preserving.  Because the system generally does not allow user-defined casting operators in situations where an object of the source type could be assigned to a reference of the destination type, there are only a few cases where user-defined casting operations would be reasonable for mutable reference types.

I would suggest as a requirement that, given `x=(SomeType)foo;` followed sometime later by `y=(SomeType)foo;`, with both casts being applied to the same object, `x.Equals(y)` should always and forevermore be true, even if the object in question was modified between the two casts.  Such a situation could apply if e.g. one had a pair of objects of different types, each of which held an immutable reference to the other, and casting either object to the other type would return its paired instance.  It could also apply with types that serve as wrappers to mutable objects, provided that the *identities* of the objects being wrapped were immutable, and two wrappers of the same type would report themselves as equal if they wrapped the same collection.

Your particular example uses mutable classes, but does not preserve any form of identity; as such, I would suggest that it is not an appropriate usage of a casting operator.

Answer (score 1):

It might be okay.

A problem with your example is that you use such example-ish names. Consider:

```
SomeMethod(long longNum)
{
  int num = (int)longNum;
  /* ... */
```

Now, when you've a good idea what a *long* and *int* means, then both the implicit cast of `int` to `long` and the explicit cast from `long` to `int` are quite understandable. It's also understandable how `3` becomes `3` and is just another way to work with `3`. It's understandable how this will fail with `int.MaxValue + 1` in a checked context. Even how it will work with `int.MaxValue + 1` in an unchecked context to result in `int.MinValue` isn't the hardest thing to grok.

Likewise, when you cast implicitly to a base type or explicitly to a derived type its understandable to anyone who knows how inheritance works what is happening, and what the result will be (or how it might fail).

Now, with *BigObject* and *SmallObject* I don't have a sense of how this relationship works. If your real types where such that the casting relationship where obvious, then casting might indeed be a good idea, though a lot of the time, perhaps the vast majority, if this is the case then it should be reflected in the class hierarchy and the normal inheritance-based casting will suffice.

Comment: Actually they're not much more than what's provided in question - but for example `BigObject` might describe an `Employee {Name, Vacation Days, Bank details, Access to different building floors etc.}`, and `SmallObject` might be a `MoneyTransferRecepient {Name, Bank details}`. There is a straightforward translation from `Employee` to `MoneyTransferRecepient`, and there is no reason to send to banking application any more data than needed.